# How does the Thin Air spell interact with Bracers of the Entangling Blast?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

Thin Air is a spell in the Frostburn book (pg. 105).

Bracers of the Entangling Blast is a magic item in the Magic Item Compendium (pg. 80)

---

The Bracers mention "damage" multiple times in its explanation text.  Yet doesn't specify anything about type(s) of damage.  I would have to assume the Bracers could be applied to spells that do various different types of damage (Fireball = HP Damage ... Thin Air = Stat Damage).

That all said, if the Bracers could be applied to stat-damage spells like Thin air, how exactly would the "half-damage" process of the Bracers apply to the rather odd stat damage distribution of the Thin Air spell? If you look at halving each attributes 1 damage allocation, you get 0.5 damage per attribute.  Per 3.5's rules, that # would get rounded up to 1.

Also, how would the Bracers' "additional  1  point  of  damage per level of the spell each round" (for 1d3 rounds) mechanic work for Thin Air's distribution spread of 1 damage point to each of the 6 attributes?

Thanks for your time and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the *bracers of the entangling blast* (*Magic Item Compendium* 80) (2,000 gp; 1 lb.), in part, says that they

> allow you [the wearer] to reduce the damage dealt by your magic to ensnare those affected by it. When you activate these *bracers*, the next spell you cast or spell-like ability you use deals only half its normal damage; however, any creature damaged by the spell becomes entangled for 1d3 rounds, taking an additional 1 point of damage per level of the spell each round on your turn. This damage is of the same type as normally dealt by the spell (or your choice if the spell deals more than one type of damage). These *bracers* have no effect on a spell or spell-like ability that doesn’t deal damage.

When the description says, "This damage is of the same type as normally dealt by the spell (or your choice if the spell deals more than one type of damage)," it's talking about *damage types*, and "[d]amage types include weapon damage (subdivided into bludgeoning, slashing, and piercing) and energy damage (positive, negative, acid, cold, electricity, fire, and sonic)" (*Player's Handbook* 307). Note that ability damage is *not* a *damage type*.

### Into *thin air*

If the DM rules that when the *bracers* description says the wearer can employ its effects by causing "the next spell [he] cast[s to] deal… only half its normal damage" that it means *also* ability damage, half of each 1 point of ability damage dealt to each ability score by the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *thin air* [trans] (*Frostburn* 105) [rounds down](http://dndsrd.net/basics.html#rounding-fractions) to *no* ability damage, and employing the *bracers* to modify the spell *thin air* causes the spell do nothing.

And if the DM rules that the when the *bracers* description says that the wearer can *reduce the damage dealt* that the description means *damage dealt of a damage type*—rather than *damage* read broadly so as to include ability damage—, employing the *bracers* to modify the spell *thin air* also causes the spell to do nothing: the spell deals no damage of any damage type (not even of type added by a later text like the ersatz damage type city that can be added to some spells *via* the metamagic feat City Magic (*Cityscape* 59-60)).

This reader suspects the *bracers* were written with spells like the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*burning hands*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#burning-hands) [evoc] (*PH* 207) and the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*lightning bolt*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#lightning-bolt) [evoc] (*PH* 248) in mind—probably to give some poor evoker a modicum of battlefield control—, with which they work just fine. However, when used in conjunction with a spell like the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*chill touch*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#chill-touch) [necro] (*PH* 209) or the aforementioned 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *thin air*, things get messy. Ultimately, ask the DM how the *bracers* work in his campaign.

Comment: Thanks, HICC.  Your examples were very helpful.  That Damage Type section in Pg. 307 (PHB) is very helpful to clarify this issue. By the way, I noticed that in Pathfinder, they modified Damage Types to include Ability Damage as a special subcomponent. Labeling it as "Special Damage Types".  At least according to the formatted core rules at D20PFSRD.com ...

Comment: @Crai You're welcome. I'm not surprised *Pathfinder* is even looser on ability damage than *3.5e* (wherein at least its codified what happens sneak attack damage is used with weaponlike spells). Personally, I think that *damage* refers almost always to *lethal damage* and *ability damage* needs to be called out separately. (That is, in the same way that cover is different from total cover—I mean, no one'd ever claim to receive total cover when he receives *just* cover, yet saying *damage* can be *ability damage* is pretty common. That's my opinion, anyway. [*Shrugs.*])

Comment: Thats probably because damage usually refers to hit point damage whereas ability damage is always specified as such as you can see on the spells chill touch, shivering touch and thin air for example.